Boundary conditions of partial differential equations.
I have a question about the boundary conditions of partial differential equations.
Suppose we want to solve the equation
$$ \mathcal {L}u = f \ \text{in} \ \Omega $$
$$ u = g \ \text{on} \ \partial \Omega. $$
where $\Omega$ is open and bounded subset of $\mathbb {R}^2 $. Can we know $ g(x) $ for all points $ x $ on the boundary of $ \Omega $? Or, if the equation comes from physics, can we only know $ g(x) $ for the points $ x $ that are measured in experiments?

As there are infinitely many functions which agree with the experimental data at the sample points (each function leading to a different solution) you need to specify the boundary data at every point on the boundary to guarantee a unique solution. Your best bet is to interpolate between the sample points to get a function $g$ defined on the entire boundary. Depending on $\mathcal{L}$, you might want to ensure the interpolation is sufficiently smooth to not cause problems (in general, this is less of an issue if $\mathcal{L}$ is elliptic).

There could be lots of functions $g$, smooth on $\partial\Omega$, interpolating the measurements. Each would lead to different a solution and trace.
